# Alternative for bean:define in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts-1, taglib

Am migrating struts 1 to 2 and facing difficulty in dealing with  .
In Struts 1 :

```
<bean:define id ="itemid" property ="totalItem" name="itemForm">
<% if (itemid > 2) {  %>....... <% } %>
```

As am completely newbie to Struts. I really dont know how to migrate this, but given a try and as expected it's not working.

```
<s:set name ="itemid" value = "totalItem" />
<Jsp:useBean id = "itemid" class ="java.lang.Integer" />
```

Comment: Struts 2 is totally different from struts 1

Comment: Yea agreed. But Struts2 has its own  taglib to achieve same we did in S1. But I can't able to make it work(bean:define)

Comment: The scriptlet code that is didn't post has no meaning to the application which should handle it before the result. It has nothing to do with the Struts1 on the server side.